# Identify connected drives in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-8, registry

I searched a bunch and am either not using the right key words or have a unique problem as I haven't found anything specific to what I'm seeing.

I've inherited a project at work, written in C++ and using WindowsAPI, that is supposed to identify USB drives that are currently connected to the machine, display those drives with manufacturer, model and serial number. This is all stored in the registry. Currently the program accesses the desired registry by:

```
 RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, TEXT("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\DeviceClasses\\{53f56307-b6bf-11d0-94f2-00a0c91efb8b}"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey)
```

Then using a combination of calls to `RegQueryInfoKey` and `RegEnumKeyEx` evaluates the key 
`/#/Control/Linked` for each entry, if Linked equals 1 the drive is connected.

This works just fine in Windows 7, the problem I'm having is porting the program to Windows 8.1 It simply doesn't return any USB drives even when they're visible in File Explorer.

Running regedit and comparing Windows 7 and 8.1 what I'm noticing is that in win8.1 when I expand the registries nowhere do I see the Control key when I expand registries, all I get is the # with no value set.

So the question is, am I missing something or did Microsoft make some changes in this regard when moving to Win8.1. If it turns out I can no longer use this registry for this purpose does anyone have a suggestion as to how I may go about doing it?

Thanks is advance for the help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt reading from that registry key has ever been officially supported and so the fact that it's changed isn't that surprising.

One way you can do this is to use [`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a list of drives in your system, and then test if each device is a USB drive using [`DeviceIoControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) command. This will fill out a [`STORAGE_DEVICE_DESCRIPTOR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800835%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure and the `BusType` member will be `BusTypeUsb` for USB devices.